# Laravel AJAX like button 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make AJAX like button in Laravel. Console returns me 500 (Internal Server Error). Here is my:

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
$('#likeForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
    var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'like-post',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'_token': token, 'user': user },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function() {
            alert('succsess');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error' );
        }})})});
```

html.blade

```
<form method="POST" id="likeForm" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}" >
<a onclick="$('#likeForm').submit()"><span>
<span class="fa fa-heart"></span> Like</a>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

Controler

```
 public function likeUser (Request $r) {
    $user_id = $r->input('user');
    Favorite::create(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'liked_id' => $user_id]);
}
```

and route

```
Route::post('like-post', 'FavoritesController@likeUser');
```

Comment: what is the error? you can check in the developer tools under the network tab, you can open the response and see a regular laravel error page.

Comment: it returns  jquery.js:8625 POST http://localhost/website/public/like-post 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: In chrome, you can go to the preview tab and see what error the server threw [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/u3z2L)

Comment: show alert and check your jquery code is working or not ?

Comment: here is error http://imgur.com/8WtWodI

Comment: Possibly the wrong 'use' statement at the top of your controller

Comment: try to put this before class use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use remove Request from method signature and write the whole method in one line:

```
 public function likeUser () {
    Favorite::create(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'liked_id' => \Request::get('user')]);
}
```

Comment: When i change controller to your suggested it returns alert("error'), but no error in console.

Comment: I think you should return back json repsonse. Check here https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses @martis

Answer (score 0):

`url('/like-post')` is the way in laravel:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"{{url('/like-post')}}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'_token': token, 'user': user },
        dataType: 'JSON',
```

Answer (score 0):

from what is see in your error image ... you are injecting the wrong class as a dependency you need to use
`Illuminate\Http\Request`
not `App\Http\Requests\Request`

the way IoC container works is it looks into your code and find what classes you need to inject and instantiates them, here you passed an abstract class which can't be instantiated.

try that and tell me if it helps.